# How to run subversion and staging environments when running Wordpress

Tags: plugins, git, testing, staging, workflow

I come from a .NET world with custom solutions, where I am used to multiple staging environments and subversion for everything.

I've been googling *a lot*, and have some questions on how handle highend Wordpress installations with a professional workflow.

I am looking for a workflow along the lines:

- Modifications can be made on a DEV server (both plugins, moving things around, modifying styles)
- Every change is in subversion
- When I make a release in subversion, it automatically builds to a QA server which runs on prod database
- When customer approves QA env, we release to prod

**But, this brings me some questions:**

Changes in Wordpress often involves plugins. Changes are based on database. A tool such as [WP Migrate DB](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/) seems essential.

I find that quite difficult to maintain correctly with this workflow in mind.

**My question is:**

- How do I implement a new "change" and get it through a workflow where we have our different environments, but also can rollback/on on a specific version from subversion?

**Own thoughts:**

- You run WP locally, and when you modify theme / plugins, you commit those changes
- You avoid comitting the WP core
- You migrate DB changes using WP Migrate DB (from DEV -> PROD db), and update the other way to keep content updated

But I am really unsure this is best practice.

Comment: You should take a look at Composer, because only using a VCS for everything isn't optimal. @Rarst has written a nice introduction about [Composer and Wordpress](http://composer.rarst.net/). It doesn't help with all you want to achieve, but if you look into it, you will see the benefits.